# Store a PDF file in the public Downloads directory [compileSdk=32]

Tags: android, kotlin, pdf, mediastore

I have an url to download a pdf file as a byte array.

I have to store it in a public directory (e.g. Downloads), so it can be easily accessed by the user.

What is the simplest way?

I tried it with Media Store, but failed to find a tutorial of how to pass a byte array to it. And Im a not even sure if Media Store can ever work with non-media files like a pdf file.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code should work without needing any permission:

```kotlin
    private fun savePdf(filename: String, content: ByteArray) {
        try {
            val savePath =
                Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)
            Files.createDirectories(savePath.toPath())
            val myExternalFile = File(savePath, filename)
            val fos = FileOutputStream(myExternalFile)
            fos.write(content)
            fos.close()
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
```